# A single word for 'regularly visited place'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that qualifies ***a place people keep coming back to***, such as their favourite restaurant, or the grocery store they usually shop at.

The word I am looking for is not 'popular'. For example, if a one-time event is well-attended, it might be qualified as 'popular' because a lot of people attend once. However, individual people will not come back to the same event again.

It should also be ***neutral***, which excludes words like 'favourite' or 'preferred'. For example, you might visit the hospital regularly because of  a health condition, but this would not be considered a favourite or preferred place.

Instead, I am looking for a word or expression that emphasises the idea of ***recurrence*** without any positive or negative connotation. The closest I have come is:

***Regularly visited*** venues are visited by the same people over and over again.

or

The local grocery store is among Joe's ***regularly visited*** places.

However, I was wondering whether a single word (noun or adjective) or a better expression to convey this idea exists.

Comment: *Watering hole;* but the term may be too local for some, too dated for others..

Comment: Why did you exclude *favorite* as in "favorite spot" ?

Comment: @Graffito The reason I do not want to use favourite is that it conveys an idea of liking. You might visit the hospital regularly because of your health, but you wouldn't call it a 'favourite spot'. Should I edit the question to make this clearer? thanks for all the answers so far!

Comment: Yes, I think that you should edit the question because most (all) responses have a positive connotation, refering to a place where you enjoy being.

Comment: @Graffito thank you, I have edited my question to highlight the recurrence aspect and the fact that it should not have any positive (or negative) connotations.

Comment: @notme Is it an adjective or a noun that you're after?

Comment: @Elian either one is fine

Comment: If it's expressly related to a drinking & socializing place in commonwealth countries, the word "Local" works in some contexts, such as "I walked down to my local, and had a pint."  This is not an answer, but might help.

Comment: What you are looking for is the name of the place that the habitué of visits.  "I have become an habitué of the local walk-in clinic because of my asthma."  Or, "I have become a habitué of Marco's because of their terrific lasagna."  But a neutral word that covers both places eludes me.

Comment: "Regular" fits the criteria.  It's a single word, and it implies the person goes there on a frequent basis.  The backwards part of this is that the word applies to the customer, not the place.  However, it does exactly what is asked: it specifies "a place people keep coming back to".  e.g., "I'm a regular at Marty's restaurant."

Answer (score 106):

***[Haunt](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haunt)*** seems a good synonym for what you seek, which according to Webster's is:

> - "a place that you go to often."

Comment: I had this in mind but was thinking "a local haunt".

Comment: thank you for your answer. Does haunt have any positive or negative connotations? Would you for example use this to refer to your local grocery store or a hospital you go to often?

Comment: I'd say yes, and probably more negative than positive, or at least more seedy than virtuous :-) For instance, I think one might use "haunt" to describe a local watering hole or nudie bar one frequents.

Comment: Are there regional differences for this word?  I live in the southern US, and I've never heard this word used in this way.

Comment: Not that I know of, but not sure.

Comment: I wouldn't have said the term was seedy, but it does have a slight implication that it's somewhere that you'd go to socially rather than e.g. for business. I'd also suggest that it's more often used in a past tense - I usually hear it used as 'my old haunts' referring to places you used to hang out when you were younger

Comment: True enough, although it doesn't have a "past tense" -- it's not a verb (at least in this context) :-) Also, note that I didn't say it was "seedy" period; I said it was "probably . . . more seedy than virtuous." You aren't likely to use your "old haunts" in reference to the church you used to attend or the stores you used to shop at. I think it's likely to be used to describe the types of places I said -- bars and other hangouts, possibly questionable in character but you're right, not necessarily.

Comment: While it's great to have pointed out **haunt**, it's completely useless to describe a (for example) supermarket.  I would say it's not so much "negative" as "only applying to a particular category of destination".  Furthermore and importantly, it tends **not to apply to** a specific say shop or cafe or nightclub, it tends to **apply more to districts** or **categories**.  So, "in my twenties I'd haunt the nightclubs of SoHo" or just "I'd haunt SoHo".  You are Less likely to say "I'd haunt Club68" or "I'd haunt Jimmy's Cafe".

Comment: @JoeBlow: Try googling (for example) "one of my old haunts" - you'll find it's quite commonly used to refer to a single bar/pub/cafe...

Comment: @JoeBlow: but you would say "Club68 is one of his usual haunts"

Comment: The only problem with the word "haunt" is that it makes people think of ghosts.

Comment: Hi PS and SM.  Yes, you're quite right that haunt can be applied to certain single things - as you say, a nightclub.  Quite simply, you would not use "haunt" for a supermarket. It's really only used for certain specific situations - let's say, places where you "hang out" (ie, for extended time periods, whether drinking or passing time in other activities). You don't describe a frequented petrol station, supermarket, etc (somewhere you might go extremely often, but don't "hang out") as a "haunt".

Answer (score 29):

**Hangout** is a common word for this these days:

> a place where a person frequently visits, esp. for socializing or recreation. 
>   A frequently visited place ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hangout))

It can carry the meaning of favorite as well, but not necessarily (note that "favorite" is added as an adjective in the example):

> a favorite place for spending time; also :  a place frequented for entertainment or for socializing 
>   The park was their favorite *hangout*. ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hangout))

Comment: Quite right, but as with "haunts" it only refers to .. hangouts.  It does not refer to places like grocery stores or petrol stations, which can be very much a "regularly visited" place by someone, but it is not a "hangout" (or "haunt")

Answer (score 24):

Not a single word, but **stomping grounds** is

> - a place where someone regularly spends time; a favorite haunt

(from the definition provided from Google for a search on this term)

Comment: Which suggests that the word "haunt" would also be a possibility (although 'stomping grounds' seems to be more commonly used nowadays).

Comment: They did ask for a single word though, there are many ways of describing this with two words.

Answer (score 10):

How about frequent?

They frequently frequent....

EDIT:

frequent (redirected from frequented)
Also found in: Legal.
fre·quent  (frē′kwənt)
adj.

1. Occurring or appearing quite often or at close intervals: frequent errors of judgment.
2. Habitual or regular: a frequent visitor to our house.
   tr.v. (also frē-kwĕnt′) fre·quent·ed, fre·quent·ing, fre·quents
   To pay frequent visits to; be in or at often: frequent a restaurant.
   [Middle English, ample, profuse, from Old French, from Latin frequēns, frequent-, crowded, numerous, frequent.]
   fre′quen·ta′tion n.
   fre·quent′er (-kwĕn′tər) n.
   fre′quent·ness n.

Comment: Why be redundant? "They frequent Joe's Diner" says everything that "They frequently frequent Joe's Diner" says.

Comment: The idea of "frequenting" a place is an appealing answer. There is no easy/obvious noun (or noun phrase) that corresponds and is commonly used (frequented place?) but it would meet the definitions of regular attendance, neutrality, and recurrence the OP asked for. "He frequented the local watering hole. He frequented his old haunts. He frequented a well-patronized hangout."

Comment: @ErikE well you don't need frequently frequent, only frequent.

Comment: this answer quite closely catches the meaning I want to convey. However, I think a noun or adjective would be more convenient.."well-frequented" comes to mind, which is close to "well-patronized".

Comment: My suggestion, for what's it worth: Add *frequented*, (A frequented grocery/bar/restaurant) a dictionary link, and maybe its definition, and this is the most sensible answer of the bunch. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frequented P.S The ‘joke’ isn't that funny, and the edit weakens your answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're in the UK and it's a pub you're referring to then the term *local* is used.

"Just popping down to the/my local for a quick pint."

Comment: And can't it also be used for takeaways, kebab shops and so on?

Comment: Just popping down to anywhere works so long as you'll only be there for a short amount of time (this can vary and is usually relative). Just popping over to my mums to grab some food, then I'll pop down the pub mate.

Answer (score 6):

An informal expression is ***[watering hole](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/watering+hole)***:

> - A social gathering place, such as a bar or saloon, where drinks are served: "a Warsaw restaurant that was once a cosmopolitan watering hole for actors and writers" (Newsweek). In both senses also called water hole.

(AHD)

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=watering&allowed_in_frame=0) the expression is from the 60's:

> - by 1965 in the figurative sense "***place where people meet and socialize over drinks."***

The reference is to the pools of water in the savannah where  wild animals gather  to drink. 
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call a grocery store (one of the example locations given) a "watering hole", except perhaps in a slangy metaphor way.

Comment: @R.M. - would you call it a haunt?

Comment: @Josh61: I for one would.  “She guessed the boys would be hanging out at one of their usual haunts in town — Dunkin Donuts, perhaps, or over at the Kwik-E-Mart.”

Comment: It's a great phrase to mean "bar", but I don't think it means "bar a person frequents" unless you qualify it, Example from UD: Heading downtown to *my favorite* watering hole.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be your "go-to" place. For example, I don't like our local supermarket, but it's still my go-to location for shopping, as it's much more convenient than anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Places that are visited over and over again by an individual are referred to as a "regular haunt."  *If you're looking for Alex, the Starbucks at the corner is one of his regular haunts.*

From a sociological perspective, places where people gather are often referred to as a "third place" space. Home is your first place, work is your second place because those are where you spend most of your time. A third place is anywhere you would go to just hang out and talk to people on a regular basis.

https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-good-life/200912/happy-places-third-places

Answer (score 3):

### *purlieu*

A good word that has not been suggested yet is **purlieu**:

> A place that one frequents.

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=purlieu))

> a frequently visited place : haunt
>
> *the restaurant, the **preferred purlieu of the theatergoing crowd**, is always packed an hour or two before showtime*

([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purlieu))

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that an expression is OK, consider **gathering place**:

> a *favorite haunt* where people gather

([WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=gathering%20place))

Another variant of "stomping grounds" (suggested by Michael above) is **"stamping ground"**:

> a favorite place where someone often goes

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stamping-ground))

Comment: One can go to a place often without gathering with anyone there.

Comment: Yes, it's a contextual answer.

Comment: Okay, but not the context of the Q.  Q contains examples like 'restaurant' and 'grocery store'.  I rarely see people ["gather" at a grocery store](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwN2r8Lma_8).  But never mind.  In closely related contexts, this is a valuable answer.

Answer (score -1):

I will go with, ***well-patronized** [venues]*. [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=well+patronized+venues&biw=359&bih=236&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CAUQ_AUoAGoVChMI3Kilz8eayQIVDAQaCh1O5ApS&cad=cbv&sei=wr1MVsJvgsZq19qLqAg#q=%22well+patronized+venue%22)

> **PATRONIZE**
>
> : to go to as a customer, **especially on a regular basis** : *We patronize the local diner*. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patronize)
>
> : to be a **frequent or regular customer** or user of (a place) [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patronize)
>
> : to **frequent** (a store, theater, restaurant, or other establishment) **as a customer**: *restaurants remaining open in the evening were well patronized* [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/patronize)
>
> *Ask owners of well-lit, well-patronized restaurants about exhibiting your art.* [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mH6YCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%22well+patronized%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMItJWBkMSayQIVC7gUCh33JQFp#v=onepage&q=%22well%20patronized%22&f=false)
>
> *At the same time, the STPB has discovered from past experience that developing tourist attractions for tourists only could be counterproductive in that foreign tourists prefer to go to those tourist attractions that are well patronized by locals.* [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=OCtACQAAQBAJ&pg=PA158&dq=%22well+patronized%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCWoVChMIraKt1sWayQIVCn4aCh0XmANb#v=onepage&q=%22well%20patronized%22&f=false)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you be able to say: "Joe's well-patronized places are the local grocery store, his workplace and the Starbucks on the corner."? Or would well-patronized simply highlight that the mentioned places are popular (For example: "Starbucks is a well-patronized coffee chain"), regardless of Joe's frequent visits.

Comment: @notme You're welcome. Personally. I wouldn't use "patronized" in the first case. I think I'd probably rather say something like "Joe's choice places are..." On top of that, I never heard of someone "patronizing" their workplace... "Starbucks is a well-patronized coffee chain" highlights the fact that Starbucks coffee stores are mostly frequented by patrons, i.e. regular customers.

Comment: These terms indicate that there are many customers, but don't adequately convey the idea that they are _repeat_ customers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA My "frequent" is not a suggestion, Mari-Lou...

Comment: Every time you update, the top answer gets an upvote :)) The word *patronize* is technically correct, but it's easily confusable with its other more derogatory meaning "to patroniz/se"  someone. And I think only for this reason, the answer hasn't been upvoted. "I patronize that bar"? "That hospital is patronized by many"?  Instead ...."The bar/club/pub [has many patrons](https://www.google.it/search?q=has+many+patrons&oq=has+many+patrons&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22has+many+patrons%22)" ....sounds more idiomatic. Don't forget the Brits spell it with an -s

Comment: @Mari-LouA My answer got a couple upvotes actually. As for the spelling -ise in BrEng, please check out this Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=patronized%2Cpatronised%2Cpatronizing%2Cpatronising%2Cpatronize%2Cpatronise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpatronized%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpatronised%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpatronizing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpatronising%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpatronize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpatronise%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It has been upvoted, you're right! But it's also been downvoted heavily, unfairly IMO.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Thing is, if context is crystal clear, I can't seem to find any fault with saying, "the local grocery store is among Joe's most patronized places," i.e "among Joe's most frequented places as a customer." :-)

Comment: Why don't you add that reflection in the answer? It's a very good one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I thought that would be obvious to just about everyone. Plus, I didn't mean to sound like I was beefing about the upvotes on Cephlin's answer...